# what is ~/.npm dir for?

Tags: macos, node.js, npm, zsh

I have installed the global npm package `jslint` and it lives here

```
$ ls -la /usr/local/bin/jslint
lrwxr-xr-x  1 lust  admin  40 Feb 12 15:31 /usr/local/bin/jslint -> ../lib/node_modules/jslint/bin/jslint.js

$ ls -la /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jslint/bin 
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 lust  staff   102 Apr 16  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x  10 lust  staff   340 Feb 12 15:31 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 lust  staff  2330 Apr 16  2012 jslint.js

$ which jslint
/usr/local/bin/jslint

$ head -3 /usr/local/bin/jslint 
#!/usr/bin/env node

var linter = require("../lib/linter");
```

So it is without any doubt whatsoever at this point that `jslint` is in fact being run from this dir and not here:

```
$ ls -la .npm/jslint/0.1.9/package/bin/         
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 lust  staff   102 Apr 16  2012 .
drwxr-xr-x  9 lust  staff   306 Feb 12 15:31 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 lust  staff  2330 Apr 16  2012 jslint.js
```

There appear to be two copies of the package, one in `/usr/local/` and one in `~/.npm`. Why is there one in `.npm` and is it safe for me to remove it?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`~/.npm` is a cache that npm uses to avoid re-downloading the same package multiple times. There's no harm in removing it. You can empty it with the command:

```
npm cache clean
```

Comment: One question about this, I tried to do ```$npm cache clean``` and got an error ```Error: EACCES, unlink```. It suggests to do as an administrator, even if I do $sudo npm install everything goes to my home/.npm dir ?? it should not be...

Comment: @alexserver I would try using `chown -r` to reclaim ownership of your `~/.npm` director, then run `npm cache clean` again.

Comment: seems that even if I do sudo npm install -g it still saves to my ~/.npm ... anyway I saw in another post that sudo npm install is not encouraged. thanks.

Comment: Do you have documentation for this directory? I can't find it anwhere, just references to `node_modules`. Is there a way to either a) set the default location to somewhere else (e.g `${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/npm`), or b) automatically disable/clean it after usage?

Comment: Since it's a cache, I've moved mine somewhere a little more suitable, ie: `cd && mv .npm .cache && ln -s .cache/.npm`.  My `.cache` tree is excluded from automatic ZFS snapshots (this is on Linux/Ubuntu; not sure whether it applies to other OS'es)

Comment: As of NPM v5, you would need to run `npm cache clean --force` because the NPM cache is "self-healing".