# I can't install React! How can I fix this?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to install React, but I obtain the error below, how can I fix them?

I'm trying to install with:

`npm install -g create-react-app`

[image: Error]

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/pedro/.npm/_cacache/tmp/09106e29
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/pedro/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pedro/.npm/_logs/2019-10-25T14_14_48_169Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did... you do that?

Comment: What version of npm are you using ? check that and upgrade.

Comment: You have the solution in the error message

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I'm using 6.11.3 version of npm

Answer (score 2):

According to the information provided by the error logs you just need to give the user under which *npm* package manager is running the proper permission to the folder `/home/pedro/.npm`.

The command provided as information should to it: `sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/pedro/.npm"`

You can read a bit more about this folder in [what is ~/.npm dir for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842201/what-is-npm-dir-for)